# Using Java generics instead of reflection to access common functionality of subclassed objects

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to figure out if generics would be a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish below (or some other way) instead of using reflection (which I currently have working just fine, but don't like it...).

I have a class library I'm using that is roughly like the following:

```
abstract class base<T>{
    public boolean method1 (String who) {
        System.out.println(who+":s");
        return true;
    }
    public T method2 (String who) {
        System.out.println(who+":d");
        // The following gives me an unchecked cast warning. I can't figure out
        // the proper way to fix that either, but it works, so I've moved on...
        // In the main program, it's this:      obj = (T) in.readObject();
        // basically deserializing the object from disk. 

        return (T) new Object();    
    }

    public abstract void load();
}

class Api1 extends base{
    @Override
    public void load(){
        System.out.println("api1:load()");
    }
}

class Api2 extends base{
    @Override
    public void load(){
        System.out.println("api2:load()");
    }
}
```

I am trying to wrap the above class library using the code below... This is what I cannot figure out how to do. The objects that are passed to init() have the same methods (method1(), method2() and load()). I don't want to write init() for each class type, instead, I just want to write it once, then have the compiler handle the details.

**UPDATE:** There are currently 6 classes that are derived from Base (with a few more likely). In the wrapper, I'm just trying to simplify access to the underlying APIs by handling various housekeeping chores automatically. In the init() method, I need to be able to call the methods of those underlying objects (based on Api1, Api2, ...), without using reflection, or without writing duplicate code for each class, or getting a bunch of unchecked warnings and/or casting...

```
class ApiWrapper<T>{

    // would like to return the type passed in if that's doable
    // e.g. public T init(T t)

    public void init(T t){

        System.out.println("inside init: "+t.getClass().toString());

        //t.method1(t.getClass().toString());
        //t.method2(t.getClass().toString());
        //t.load();
    }
}

class api1Wrap extends ApiWrapper {
    Api1 api = new Api1();

    public api1Wrap(){
        init(api);
    }
}

class api2Wrap extends ApiWrapper {
    Api2 api = new Api2();
    public api2Wrap(){

        init(api);
    }
}

public class GenericApiWrapper {
    private final api1Wrap api1;
    private final api2Wrap api2;

    public GenericApiWrapper() {
        this.api1 = new api1Wrap();
        this.api2 = new api2Wrap();
    }
}
```

From a main() somewhere ...

```
GenericApiWrapper gaw = new GenericApiWrapper();
```

It feels to me like generics are the right approach for this type of thing, but I've been trying all sorts of combinations, and reviewing various articles and examples, but I just can't seem to figure out the proper approach. If this has already been asked and answered, please point me to it. I can't seem to find it, probably because I'm not sure how to describe what I'm trying to do. :) I've been looking at the Java Generics FAQ as well, but I haven't found what I'm looking for... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will apiWrapper wrap objects that extend base?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, but I can say that your code is full of raw types (don't, ever, use raw types), and that `return (T) new Object();` doesn't make any sense. T can be any class, and if a method is supposed to return an object of type T, then it should return an object of type T. Unless T is Object, new Object() is not of type T. So this code will **always** cause exceptions at runtime. You also don't respect the basic Java naming conventions, BTW. Classes start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: It is not clear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, apiWrapper wraps object that extend base. I will try to clarify what I'm trying to achieve by adding more to the post. But essentially, the init() method makes lots of calls to the methods in the underlying base and api# classes. Right now, I'm using reflection to get at them, but I'm searching for a better/cleaner way.

Comment: *"I need to be able to call the methods of those underlying objects, without using reflection"* - and exactly why can't you call these methods?

Comment: @lexicore The compiler says it doesn't know anything about **t.method1(String)**, etc., when I try to access them inside the init() method of the ApiWrapper() class.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the feedback. This is a stripped down sample. Rest assured, all my classes start with an uppercase letter. :) As far as the return (T) new Object() not making sense, I agree. I put it there as a placeholder so I could get the code to compile. In the actual program, the object being cast is actually of the correct type, I just am not sure how to address the warning properly. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You should tell the compiler that `T` (in context of `ApiWrapper`) is actually some extension of `base`. Like `<T extends base<?>>`. Better use different letters for different type parameters, like `ApiWrapper<T, A extends base<T>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In generics you should specify the type you want to use, in this case you replace the `T` with for example `Api1` otherwise the compiler uses `Object`:

```
class api1Wrap extends ApiWrapper<Api1> {
   Api1 api = new Api1();

   public api1Wrap(){
      init(api);
   }
}
```

Also you could improve your code by simple implementing one single class and creating several instances with different types, this is the idea behind generics.

UPDATE: 
If you also specify that `T` extends base, then the compiler is able to find the methods.

Take a look at this:

```
class ApiWrapper<K, T extends base<K>>{

    private T t;

    public ApiWrapper(T t){
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void wrap(){
        init(t)
    }

    private void init(T t){
        t.method1("hello");
        K k = t.method2("world");
    }
}


ApiWrapper<Object, Api1> apiWrapper1 = new ApiWrapper<>(new Api1());
```

Comment: Thank you! Between this and @lexicore's suggestions, I was able to get this working. I still have the issue in the base class with regards to the unchecked type cast, but I'll keep at it until I figure out how to properly address it. One thing: I had to drop the base<K> above to make it work i.e. <K, T extends base> made it all work. Otherwise I would get an error when declaring apiWrapper1, ...

Comment: I think I see the issue with unchecked cast... Indeed what I'm doing there makes no sense. In the app, that method returns the result of the deserialization of the object (which would be an Api1 or an Api2, ..., but it doesn't make sense that the base class would know anything about them. I'll redesign that so it makes more sense. Thanks again!